# Can telekinesis or wind affect incorporeal creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, incorporeal

Are incorporeal creatures affected by the following effects?

1. Telekinesis
2. Object thrown by Telekinesis
3. Wind caused by fan
4. Wind caused by Control Wind spell or Control Weather spell

Answer (score 5):

The description of "Incorporeal subtype" in MM (3.5e) includes the following (emphasis mine):

> An incorporeal creature has no physical body.  It can be harmed only
>   by other incorporeal creatures, magic weapons or creatures that strike
>   as magic weapons, and spells, spell-like abilities or supernatural
>   abilities.  Even when hit by spells or magic weapons, it has a 50%
>   chance to ignore any damage from a corporeal source (except for …)
>
> ...In fact they cannot take any physical action that would move or
>   manipulate an opponent or its equipment, *nor are they subject to such
>   actions*.

So, this leads to:

1. No, as per the last sentence quoted above.  Telekinesis acts to "move or manipulate an opponent or its equipment" but incorporeal opponents are specifically immune to such effects.
2. No (except for a magic weapon or, against incorporeal undead only, holy water, each of which would have a 50% miss chance)
3. No - corporeal air has no effect
4. No - corporeal air still has no effect even though a spell started it moving